# JMETER (Beanshell): Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 4, column 25. Encountered: "u" (117), after : "\'s"

Tags: java, json, jmeter, beanshell

In JMETER I have HTTP query which returns JSON String as following:

`{"url":"/some/path?Id=343\u0026"}`

I'm trying to parse parameter Id from it with `BeanShell` sampler:

```
url = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
int start=url.indexOf('Id=');
int end = url.indexOf('u0026')-1;
newId=url.substring(start,end);
vars.put("newId", newId);
```

and get an error: `Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 4, column 25.  Encountered: "u" (117), after : "\'s"`

Any ideas?

So it seems like backslash confuses the parser. Tried some Java `String` operations (`replaceAll`, `URLEncoder.encode`) - none of them seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON URL contained extra parameter: {"url":"/some/path?Id=343\u0026success=1"}, so following code worked:

```
url = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
int start=url.indexOf("Id=")+3;
int end = url.indexOf("success=1")-6; //note: "\u0026" is 6 characters
newId=url.substring(start,end);
vars.put("newId", newId);
```

Answer (score 0):

\u0026 is actually one character, not 6. Change line 3 to

```
int end = url.indexOf("\u0026");
```

By the way, I am not sure about your usage of single quotes. I suspect BeanShell is converting from a character array to a String in order to make it work. Best make them double quotes, just in case.

Comment: Didn't work. Although found a workaround. Cause url contained more parameters, I used another string ("success=1") to locate Id:
{"url":"/some/path?Id=343\u0026success=1"}.

Comment: Interesting, I tested the code in a Java test class and it worked just fine.